# How Do I create a log using performance monitor in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

A company I deal with have their own server, and a couple of sites using SQL server 2005 on it.  They are getting random, intermitten freezes and its pointing to SQL Server so the company who they got the server from said to

"create a log using performance monitor in SQL"

I have RD Access... Is this a simple setting I just need to put on?  Or is it more technical?

Answer (score 1):

With SQL Performance Monitor you can create Data Collector Sets

Start SQL Performance Monitor - User Defined (Right click) - New - Data Collector Set

It will create a file in a directory you can change during the wizard.

Run it - Stop it.

There is a "log" you can open with SQL Performance Monitor

Answer (score 0):

Use SQL Profiler and when you setup the new trace you can choose "Save to file" as an option.

Depending on your usage, you may need to filter out a lot of the trace to only show relevent databases and/or queries.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. The performance monitor creates the tables that you need and log the information that you want.